# Laravel - Doesn't send messages from the site

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailtrap

**Laravel 7.0**

Sending email from localhost does not work. He writes that he cannot send a message without an email, but I put all the fields with emails.
Created everything with docs.laravel.

**Route\web.php**

```
Route::get('contact', 'ContactsController@index')->name('contacts'); // ContactsPages
Route::post('contact/send',  'MailSetting@send_form'); // ContactsPages(FORM_FeedBack)
```

**App\Http\Controller\MailSetting**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\MailClass;

class MailSetting extends Controller
{
    public function send_form(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $message = $request->message;

        Mail::to('test@mail.ru')->send(new MailClass($name, $email, $message));
    }
}
```

**App\Mail\MailClass**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MailClass extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $name;
    protected $email;
    protected $message;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name, $email, $message)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.contact-mail')
            ->with([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'message' => $this->message,
        ])
        ->subject('New MESSAGE ');
    }
}
```

**.env_file**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=2d1*******3e1d
MAIL_PASSWORD=62e*******db9
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**Config\Mail.php**

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', ''),
        ],
```

**cotacts.blade**

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <form action="{{ route('contacts') }}/send" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<button type="send">Send message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**email_view**

```
Name   : {{ json_encode($name,TRUE)}} <br>
Email  : {{ json_encode($email,TRUE)}} <br>
Message: {{ json_encode($message,TRUE)}} <br>
```

After the error appeared for the first time, I decided that I could change the settings on Gmail, changed them, but there another error appears.

Comment: where is the "from" address set?

Comment: From address is required for sending emails even when host is set to mailtrap. You may either set `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=some@value.com` on the `.env` file or add `->from('some@value.com')` in the build function of `MailClass` - maybe after `->subject('NEW MESSAGE')`

Comment: @Donkarnash, Yeeeep ! thx, it's WORK  !!!

Comment: But there was a problem, when I send a letter (test), then a set of characters comes for the place of the name, and the field with the message is completely empty, it shows curly braces and nothing else.

Comment: @Dizmuzz I have posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`From Address` is required (**A MUST**) for sending emails - even when the host is set to mailtrap.io

It can be set globally for the app in the `.env` file

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=some@value.com
```

Or it can be set/overridden per Mailable class in the build method

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.contact-mail')
        ->with([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'message' => $this->message,
        ])
        ->subject('New MESSAGE ')
        ->from('some@value.com');
}
```